Plesk Firewall blocking internet access for WireGuard clients
I'm currently facing an issue I can not fix myself. The initial idea was to setup WireGuard on my server running Plesk. I've searched a bit the internet and found this really nice tutorial. It really helped me to set up everything on my server and configuring new clients. The only thing I've changed a bit inside the configuration is the PostUp and PostDown script to fit my network interface:
PostUp: iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown: iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
I've checked everything, enabled all services, restarted my server (just to be sure) and configured my iPhone by using the provided QR code.
I was really happy to see that the handshake worked and I can see my internal pages hiding inside Plesk using:
<Location />
    Require ip 10.252.1.0/24
</Location>

But then I found something out: I have no internet access.
I've spent a lot of time going back through the settings, checking my IP forwarding and everything, but was unable to find the issue. So I've opened Plesk again and checked for the Firewall and turned it off for a minute. To my surprise, I was able to get internet on my iPhone. So I've added some rules to the Firewall:

Allow incoming traffic on port 51820/udp (done during install already)
Allow incoming traffic from 10.252.1.0/24 on all ports
Allow outgoing traffic from 10.252.1.0/24 on all ports

I've saved the rules and turned the Firewall back on but found out that the internet access was gone again. I've checked the IP tables and everything, but I'm stuck.
I would be glad for any advice I can get to get the internet access working for my VPN clients!

With -A, you're adding rules at the end. The question is at the end of what other rules. Have you checked the ruleset that Plesk generates, e.g. iptables -S FORWARD? If you go through it from top to bottom, is there a rule that would block traffic before it reaches your rule at the very end?
